# Create or Change multipage TIFFs

Tags: c++, imagemagick, tiff

I try to compose new and modify existing multipage TIFFs using Magick++.
Does someone know how I can do this?

I can read a specific page using this code:

```
Image * img = new Image("path/to/image.tif[0]"); //read page 0
```

But how can I save changes back to the TIFF? and how can I add new pages?
Google could only tell me things about splitting TIFFs in singe page ones.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never tried it but what about the `writeImages` function. Docs are [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/STL.html).
From the docs

> Write images in container to file specified by string imageSpec_